# Can the Notched Pickaxe be used to enchant other items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the Notched Pickaxe with its smithing enchantment.  I would like to disenchant this item and apply it to another weapon.  I'm scared to try it as I don't want to lose my pickaxe.  Can this enchantment be applied to another weapon when learned from disenchanting the pickaxe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the [Notched Pickaxe](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Notched_Pickaxe) can be disenchanted and its effects applied to other weapons.

> The Notched Pickaxe can be disenchanted to learn the "Notched Pickaxe Effect," which can be used to enchant to other weapons. Points towards Smithing are capped at 5. The shock damage varies as per standard Enchanting rules

Comment: Sweet!  I had previously been told by Wiki that it could be disenchanted, but that the effect could not be applied to other weapons.  Thanks!

Comment: @MaurerPower - No problem.  Welcome to Gaming.StackExchange!

Comment: Just for a tidbit of clarity, when it says points toward Smithing are capped at 5, it's referring to both hands. Dual-wielding Notched Pickaxes doesn't help. ;)